# How to have selected the option value from a dropbox when the value is taken from the DB?

Tags: php, mysql

From mySQL and PHP I get the option value from the DB. I have a edit.php page where the user can edit his previous choice. How can I have the selected value shown if the below is HTML and not from the Database?

Thank you

```
 <option value="2014">2014</option>
 <option value="2013">2013</option>
 <option value="2012">2012</option>
 <option value="2011">2011</option>
 <option value="2010">2010</option>
 <option value="2009">2009</option>
 <option value="2008">2008</option>
```

Comment: Show your php code that access the option value

Comment: <option value="2014" <?php if($row['option_name']=='2014' echo 'selected';?>>2014</option> try this in you cose

Comment: <option value="2013" selected >2013</option>, this will show selected value on page. Also pls put some code snippet so that we can help you.

Comment: <option value="2014" <?php if($row['option_name']=='2014' echo 'selected="selected"';?>>2014</option> Use this...keep the selected in a double quote actually the syntax is selected = "selected". If the value matches the echo this.

Comment: also use loop, it saves your time.

Answer (score 1):

let say you have array $abc containing the data to populate the select DOM

and you have array $qwe containing detail of the user(or whatever module you editing)

for array

```
<option value="<?php echo $abc['name_of_column'];?>" <?php if($abc['name_of_column'] == $qwe['name_of_column'] ){echo "selected='selected'";}?>>2014</option>
```

for object

```
<option value="<?php echo $abc->name_of_column;?>" <?php if($abc->name_of_column == $qwe->name_of_column){echo "selected='selected'";}?>>2014</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<option value="2014" <?php if($row['option_name']=='2014') echo 'selected';?> >2014</option>
<option value="2013" <?php if($row['option_name']=='2013') echo 'selected';?> >2013</option>
<option value="2012" <?php if($row['option_name']=='2012') echo 'selected';?> >2012</option>
<option value="2011" <?php if($row['option_name']=='2011') echo 'selected';?> >2011</option>
<option value="2010" <?php if($row['option_name']=='2010') echo 'selected';?> >2010</option>
<option value="2009" <?php if($row['option_name']=='2009') echo 'selected';?> >2009</option>
<option value="2008" <?php if($row['option_name']=='2008') echo 'selected';?> >2008</option>
```

Try this code

Answer (score 0):

put the selected year into php variable $y, then:

```
 <option value="2014" <? if ($y=='2014') echo 'selected'; ?>>2014</option>
 <option value="2013" <? if ($y=='2013') echo 'selected'; ?>>2013</option>
 <option value="2012" <? if ($y=='2012') echo 'selected'; ?>>2012</option>
 <option value="2011" <? if ($y=='2011') echo 'selected'; ?>>2011</option>
 <option value="2010" <? if ($y=='2010') echo 'selected'; ?>>2010</option>
 <option value="2009" <? if ($y=='2009') echo 'selected'; ?>>2009</option>
 <option value="2008" <? if ($y=='2008') echo 'selected'; ?>>2008</option>
```